# Open sourced LiDAR dataset?

Tags: data-request, images

I mean laser ranging data from a ground based, moving vehicle. As it's the data the self-driving algorithms chew on, I'd assume there must be some interest.

Comment: does this help? http://gisgeography.com/top-6-free-lidar-data-sources/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried [University of Michigan](http://robots.engin.umich.edu/SoftwareData/Ford)?  They have some large datasets available for download from their test runs around campus:

> We provide a dataset collected by an autonomous ground vehicle
>   testbed, based upon a modified Ford F-250 pickup truck. The vehicle is
>   outfitted with a professional (Applanix POS LV) and consumer (Xsens
>   MTI-G) Inertial Measuring Unit (IMU), a Velodyne 3D-lidar scanner, two
>   push-broom forward looking Riegl lidars, and a Point Grey Ladybug3
>   omnidirectional camera system. Here we present the time-registered
>   data from these sensors mounted on the vehicle, collected while
>   driving the vehicle around the Ford Research campus and downtown
>   Dearborn, Michigan during November-December 2009. The vehicle path
>   trajectory in these datasets contain several large and small-scale
>   loop closures, which should be useful for testing various state of the
>   art computer vision and SLAM (Simultaneous Localization and Mapping)
>   algorithms.

Answer (score 4):

The [University of Wisconsin Lidar Group](http://lidar.ssec.wisc.edu/) provides several LIDAR data sets [here](http://hsrl.ssec.wisc.edu/).

The Institute of Meteorology of the University of Hamburg, Germany, provides LIDAR data [here](http://icdc.cen.uni-hamburg.de/projekte/hdcp2/observational-data/long-term-observations/local-observations/sups-joy-dlidst00-l1-any.html).

You might also have a look into the [EBAS database](http://ebas.nilu.no) of the NILU (Norwegian Institute for Air Research). It hosts several air quality datasets from all over Europe and also from some non-European locations. Maybe, there is also LIDAR data available.

Answer (score 3):

NCLT - The University of Michigan North Campus Long-Term Vision and LIDAR Dataset
http://robots.engin.umich.edu/nclt/

You can found another lidar dataset in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.08775.pdf